# BPM with Event-driven Architecture & Closure?

Tags: closures, jbpm, business-process-management, activiti, event-driven

I have read the book [Activiti in Action](http://www.manning.com/rademakers2/) and I think I have a good idea what a BPM does.  However, I am not drinking the kool-aid of using BPMN2 nor BPEL as the backbone for specifying a workflow.  The script tasks are also quite clumsy to define and maintain with the confine of a static language like Java.

After reading the book I think to myself, wouldn't it be cool if the BPM system can make use of an event-driven architecture and closures for defining activity?  Preferably in a dynamic language that support them natively?

Does such BPM project exist?  and if no, do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check drools and jBPM? That's the main idea behind those projects. To provide a Knowledge oriented platform to define your flexible processes helped by the Rule Engine. 
It also comes with Drools Fusion for the Event Processing capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, yes I will do some research on jBPM next but I believe it is similar to Activiti and has the same downsides I've mentioned in the question.